# Add and remove from MAP with limited size

Tags: java, dictionary, guava, multimap

I want a limited size map with some duplicated keys. When size is reached I want delete the oldest entry.

for example, this data set:

```
MAX_SIZE=5;
map.put(100,"OLDEST");
map.put(101,"XXXX");
map.put(101,"YYYY");
map.put(102,"ZZZZ");
map.put(103,"GGGG");
```

Then I want to insert a new entry in the map

```
myLength = map.size()
if(myLength>=MAX_SIZE){
   map.remove(the OLDEST)
}    
map.put(105,"NEW")
```

I was thinking in guava multimap, but how delete the oldest entry in multimap?

They KEY is a Long, maybe  I need do a for?  (not efficient)

```
oldest=MAX_LONG
for(Long key:map){
     if(key<oldest){
           oldest=key
      }
}
map.remove(oldest)
```

Comment: which implementation of map interface you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [LinkedListMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/LinkedListMultimap.html): it preserves the insertion order, so removing the oldest entry is just a matter of removing the first element of the list returned by [entries()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/LinkedListMultimap.html#entries%28%29)